# In performing cross validation, is it always required to use a learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Sorry if my question makes no sense to you.

I'm troubled because as of now I have a program that can recognize sign language. The whole process it takes to recognize a gesture done by a user goes like this:

1. User performs a gesture.
2. The gesture done by the user is recorded by Kinect and is saved as a temp data.
3. That temp data is then compared to all words in the library using Dynamic Time Warping.
4. After comparing the temp data to all the words in the library, the one which the temp data is most similar to is printed on a screen.

Now what troubles me is:

1. Is Dynamic Time Warping a learning algorithm?
2. If not, how do I perform cross validation using Dynamic Time Warping?

Answer (score 0):

No, DTW is a method used to look at the similarity between two time sequences. It is an algorithm but not a learning algorithm. In your case, signal generated from Kinect is compared with the signals already saved for different words using DTW algorithm.